# exec sp_tables_ex returns nothing on a server I can find using exec sp_linkedservers

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, openquery

I'm trying to find data in a database which hasn't been used that much.

I've seen that it is a linked server using:

```
exec sp_linkedservers
```

which returns the servername, `TheSRV` along with for instance its catalog name `S100`.

I then try to find information about which tables are present in the linked server, `TheSRV`.

For this I try to use:

```
exec sp_tables_ex TheSRV
```

but this returns only the headers, without any data.

I can do a Query using openquery like this:

```
Select name, date From OPENQUERY(TheSRV, 'Select Name, Date from S100.F1.TableName')
```

which returns valid data.

How can I find the information I need about tables present, when I can't find a list of tables?

Comment: What do you mean about only headers? Are you looking for a list of tables, a list of columns for each of those tables, or are you looking for something which selects a few rows from each so you can see example data?

Comment: @Bridge        With only the headers I mean that when I try to use Exec sp_tables_ex TheSRV I only get the headers correlated to that Query, i.e. `TABLE_CAT`, `TABLE_SCHEM` among Three more, but no data corresponding to the headers. I want to find out a list of tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use one of the standard ways of listing schema objects, qualifying server name as part of the four part naming convention:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TheSRV.S100.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
WHERE  T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

To see the columns in each of those tables:

```
SELECT C.*
FROM   TheSRV.S100.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
       INNER JOIN TheSRV.S100.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
               ON T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME
                  AND T.TABLE_SCHEMA = C.TABLE_SCHEMA
WHERE  T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
ORDER BY C.TABLE_NAME, C.ORDINAL_POSITION
```